# jquery function if one or other event takes place

Tags: jquery, function

What would be the best way to write

**IF**

```
$("#div1").click()
```

**OR**

```
$("#div2").hover()
```

**THEN**

```
{ do some function }
```

I know how to chain events together that share common element, but how would I do multiple events for multiple elements (and sorry if my terminology is incorrect!).

Thanks for your help!

**edit:** To clarify, I'm wondering if it is possible to have one function run when *either* of the two aforementioned events takes place. So if A or B happens then do C.

Comment: what do you mean multiple elements? elements that shares multiple event handlers?

Comment: different elements, i.e. #div1 or #div2, where one is clicked, or the other is hover, for example.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/GuuWt/

Comment: @Mahan Have you tested your fiddle?

Comment: or like this? http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/GuuWt/1/

Comment: @Mahan So why your selector doesn't select the elements?

Comment: @undefined just edited it already sorry..

Comment: @iight then the answer of mkoryak is already correct!

Comment: @Mahan, Please use the answer section if you are going to suggest an answer. Also, instead of posting comments one after the next, you can edit your comments and save space. Otherwise, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whats wrong with:

```
var fn = function(){ ... }

$("#div1").click(fn);
$("#div2").hover(fn);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = function(e) { console.log(e); };

$("#div1").click(x)
$("#div2").hover(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

For 1 element and 2 or more events:

```
$("#div").on("click hover", function(){
   console.log("execute");
});
```

For 2 elements, each with 1 event:

```
function print(a) {
   console.log(a);
}

$("#div1").on("click", function(){
   print("click");
});

$("#div2").on("hover", function(){
   print("hover");
});
```